# My gcc compiler giving me warning for implicit declaration of function even though the declaration is clearly given in the code

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors

My GCC compiler giving me warning:

> power.c: In function ‘main’:
> power.c:9:36: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘power’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
> 9 |   printf("%d \t %d \t %d \n", i+1, power(2,i), power(-6,i));

whereas I have clearly declared implicit for the power function, which I give in the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
        int i;

        printf("%s \t %s \t %s \n", "Powers", "of 2", "of -6");
        for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
                printf("%d \t %d \t %d \n", i+1, power(2,i), power(-6,i));
        return 0;

}


int power(int base, int n){
        int i, p;

        p = 1;
        for (i=0; i <= n; ++i)
                p = p * base;
        return p;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to forward declare your `power` function before you call it:

```
int power(int base, int n);

int main(){
        int i;

        printf("%s \t %s \t %s \n", "Powers", "of 2", "of -6");
        for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
                printf("%d \t %d \t %d \n", i+1, power(2,i), power(-6,i));
        return 0;

}
```

Or, you could just move the definition of `power` before `main`.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see that actually, asked a really stupid question. LoL

Comment: A definition is always also a declaration. A declaration which is not a definition is generally called a forward-declaration where the distinction matters. Most of the time, a declaration is enough to compile code, sometimes (deduced return-type) the definition is needed.